# RecyclerView NullPointerException Issue

Tags: android-recyclerview

I have set the layout manager for recyclerview, but still I am getting below error.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.onMeasure
```

Fragment which has recyclerview:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.gridContainer);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager l = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(l);

        recyclicAdapter = new RecyclicAdapter(getActivity(),getData());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclicAdapter);

        return layout;
    }
```

Please look into this and let me know what went wrong.

i have posted adapter code below as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Adaper Code:

Adapter to write the data into the recyclerview:

```
   private LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<String> arrayList = Collections.emptyList();
    RecyclicAdapter(Context context,List<String> data){
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.arrayList = data;

    }

    @Override
    public KViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sinrow,parent,false);
        KViewHolder holder = new KViewHolder(v);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(KViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.textView.setText(arrayList.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {return arrayList.size();}

    class KViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView textView;
        public KViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.passtext);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
                        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
                        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```